# file upload validation returns application/force-download

Tags: php, file, validation, upload

I have a problem when uploading files to my web server. I created a validation in order to limit the uploads to my server, inspired by another post here on stackoverflow. The idea is that the user should only be able to upload certain file types to the server in order to avoid that he can upload scripts etc.

```
$upfile = $_FILES['cont2'];
if($upfile) {
        $acceptable = array(
            'application/pdf', //.pdf
            'application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml', //.pdf
            'application/vnd.ms-excel', //.xls
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', //.pptx
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow', //.ppsx
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', //.xlsx
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template', //.xltx
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', //.docx
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template', //.dotx
            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', //.ppt
            'application/onenote', //.onetoc
            'audio/x-ms-wma', //.wma
            'video/x-ms-wmv', //.wmv
            'application/msword', //.doc
            'application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument', //.xps
            'audio/mpeg', //.mpga
            'video/mpeg', //.mpeg
            'video/mp4', //.mp4
            'audio/mp4', //.mp4a
            'application/mp4', //.mp4
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation', //.odp
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet', //.ods
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text', //.odt
            'application/vnd.sun.xml.calc', //.sxc
            'application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template', //.std
            'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer', //.sxw
            'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop', //.psd
            'text/plain', //.txt
            'text/x-vcard', //.vcf
            'application/xml', //.xml
            'application/zip', //.zip
            'application/x-rar-compressed', //.rar
            'video/jpeg',
            'text/calendar',
            'video/x-flv',
            'video/x-msvideo',
            'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/bmp',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png'
        );
    if(!in_array($_FILES['cont2']['type'], $acceptable) && !empty($_FILES["cont2"]["type"])) die('<b>File Format not allowed.</b>');
```

The problem now is that the validation process doesn't always work. When I upload a .jpg image, it works, then I tried with a PDF, and it didn't work. So I tried to find out what the type of the PDF was by making a simple

```
echo $_FILES['cont2']['type'];
```

and it returned **application/force-download**.
However, the same piece of script worked on the server in another script file, with the same PDF. Any ideas what the problem could be and how I can precisely solve it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Update: sorry, the same piece of script does NOT work in another file. so I'll just need to have that piece solved with the application/force-download